# How to test my component with ActivatedRoute?

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to test a component with 2 resolvers (pagesResolver and UploadResolver) :

my component:

```
export class AdminPagesComponent implements OnInit {
  fileUploads$: Observable<FileUpload[]>;
  pagesList$: Observable<Page[]>;
  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.pagesSub = this.route.parent.data
      .pipe(
        map((data: { pages: Observable<Page[]> }) => {
          this.pagesList$ = data.pages
          return data.pages
        }),
        mergeMap(res => res.pipe(
          map(pages => {
            this.pagesService.setPages(pages);
            console.log(pages)
          })
        ))
      )
      .subscribe();
    this.uploadSub = this.route.parent.data
      .pipe(
        map((data: { upload: Observable<FileUpload[]> }) => {
          this.fileUploads$ = data.upload
          return data.upload
        })
      )
      .subscribe();
  }    
}
```

Here is my test file :

```
describe('AdminPagesComponent', () => {
  let component: AdminPagesComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AdminPagesComponent>;
  const initialState = {};

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [AdminPagesComponent],
      imports: [],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: ActivatedRoute,
          useValue: {
            parent: {
              data: {

              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AdminPagesComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

If I run test like this, I have this karma Error :

```
TypeError: this.route.parent.data.pipe is not a function
```

My component is working correctly and data is well passed to the template with Async pipe.
How can I make my test success please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost had it. You need `data` to return an `Observable` in your case.

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
....
providers: [
        {
          provide: ActivatedRoute,
          useValue: {
            parent: {
              data: of({
                 pages: undefined,
                 upload: undefined // mock these two properties however you wish.
              }),
            }
          }
        }
      ]
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to testing modules. What do you mean with "mock these two properties however you wish" please ? How can I do that ? I did the changes in my code, and I got this karma error : " Cannot read property 'pipe' of undefined"

Comment: I think i have done what you said by creating fake pages and upload and replaced "undefined" by those variables. But now i have this error : "InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'"

Comment: Ok i found the solution: data: of({
                pages: of([pageMock]),
                upload: of([uploadMock])
              })